# Function to get data-id from div

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
  });

  $('.carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    alert($(".active").data("item-id"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-inner ">
  <div class="item   slideDate" data-id="03-03-2019">
    <div class="kalendarzMalyDataZabacz  kalendarzMalyDataZabaczCor">03<br>03</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item  slideDate active" data-id="04-03-2019">
    <div class="kalendarzMalyDataZabacz  kalendarzMalyDataZabaczCor">04<br>03</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item  slideDate" data-id="05-03-2019">
    <div class="kalendarzMalyDataZabacz  kalendarzMalyDataZabaczCor">05<br>03</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is bootstrap carouser. It's work fine. I want show in alert box my visible date (data-id with active slide).

How can I make it?

My actually function with alert is not working :(

**UPDATE**

it's not working. Here Is my full code: https://pastebin.com/b2bCWv9u with this div

Comment: In your HTML you are using `data-id="date"` while in your JS you're using `.data("item-id")`. Either use `data-item-id` and `data('item-id')` or `data-id` and `data('id')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the date is actually stored in the data-id attribute, you should use jquery's [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method

so the following code should generally work :

```
alert($(".active").prop("data-id"));
```

Comment: this return undefined

Comment: try to change $(".active") to $(".item.slideDate.active") ?

Comment: its return undefined :(

Comment: could make a paste with the full page html so we can debug ?

Comment: You have to use .prop("data-id") not .prop("item-id")

Comment: it's not working. Here Is my full code: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/pub/sample.txt

Comment: You are still using .attr("item-id") instead of attr("data-id") , the item-id simply doesn't exist in those divs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the data into data-id maybe you need to use

```
$(".active").attr("data-id")
```

then your code look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: false
  });

  $('.carousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
    alert($(".active").attr("data-id"));
  });
});
```

**EDIT:**
Maybe you have more than one DOM whit the `.active` class
Try replace the alert with this code is more specific.

```
$(".item.slideDate.active").attr("data-id")
```

more info: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: this return undefined :(

Comment: Maybe you have more that one  `.active` class

Comment: it's not working. Here Is my full code: https://pastebin.com/b2bCWv9u with this div

Comment: i edit my answer because i do not write the atribute name.

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents of the attribute data-id (like in link) you have to use

```
$('selector').attr("data-id")
```

// will return the string "123"

You can use .data() (if you use newer jQuery >= 1.4.3)

`$('selector').data("id")`

// will return the number 123

Comment: its return undefined :(

Comment: @trafiek can you create a jsfiddle where you having this issue?